# How do I get the name of the code signing identity from a provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, provisioning-profile

I have some provisioning profiles like

```
./profiles/first.mobileprovision
./profiles/second.mobileprovision
./profiles/third.mobileprovision
```

I would like to know the code signing identity for each of those.  Is there a command what could print that (in the standard format like "iPhone Distribution: Developer Name (ABCDE12345)" )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dump the profile in readable form using...

```
security cms -D -i [filename]
```

I'm not sure that the information you're looking for is there in the form you want, however.  If I grep the output for "key", I get the following list...

```
<key>AppIDName</key>
<key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
<key>CreationDate</key>
<key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<key>ExpirationDate</key>
<key>Name</key>
<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
<key>TeamIdentifier</key>
<key>TeamName</key>
<key>TimeToLive</key>
<key>UUID</key> 
<key>Version</key>
```

...but that may be related to the profile type that I selected.

Comment: Very good. How would you know if this is a developer profile or an adhoc distribution profile?

Comment: I don't know if there's any definitive description of the output.  I can see that what I put in the answer is ad hoc because it has the "Provisioned Devices" key.  An enterprise profile I also tried has "<key>ProvisionsAllDevices</key>" with a "true" value instead.

Comment: I believe you'll want to pull the value for the `TeamName` key.